# iPhone: How to continuously play unplayed podcasts?

Tags: iphone, podcasts, podcasts.app

I am on an iPhone 7 Plus running iOS 10.3.3 and the Podcasts app (the default podcast app by Apple) does not continuously play unplayed podcasts that I've already downlaoded. It plays one at a time and every time I must manually click on the next one. Very annoying.
It's been like this for 6+ months now. I've restarted the phone, I've checked the moon button at the bottom of the screen to make sure it is marked as "Off". I also tried setting it to 1 hour and then back to Off...all to no avail. Curiously enough even after setting the moon button to one hour, and then scrolling to the end and letting it finish, it still does not even auto play the next unplayed podcast.

Any ideas?

Comment: Just to be sure... Is the issue that the default podcast app stopped working or that you are not sure if it can continuously play and want to know how to do it, if it is possible? If it stopped working, then pretty much the only thing you can do is complain to apple and possibly use a third party app. Either way, I'd really recommend Downcast *wink*.

Comment: I'm not sure it "stopped working" or if it ever worked or is it even supposed to continuously play unplayed podcasts?

Comment: After taking a look at that app... I remember why I stopped using it. It's not very good. It seems there are two ways to do continuous play. I read online that if you make a playlist you can do it, but I couldn't find how to make a playlist on the device. Maybe it can only be done through iTunes?. The other way is "play next" or "add to up next". As in click the menu icon (3 dots) next to an episode and choose one of them. And it's added to a queue. I couldn't find a list of queued episodes though, which makes it a bit difficult to use.

Answer (score 1):

I have had the same issue since iOS 11 update. I can’t find a way to do this in the app other than constructing a playlist manually which is ridiculous. However, if you ask Siri to play unplayed podcasts, it will play them all continuously. Bit of a hack while waiting for Apple to fix.

Answer (score 1):

I found an answer here:
https://discussions.apple.com/thread/8086917

Summary - the "All Unplayed" part of the "Library" is a station like any other, and if you play the topmost podcast in the list it appears to also queue up the rest in "up next".  Not sure what happens at the end of that - whether new downloads will get added.

The "Listen Now" station does not act like this in my experience.

Comment: The link you provided doesn't work.

Comment: Hmm. It worked just now when I clicked it...

Comment: Oddly, works for Video podcasts (CNet) but doesn't work for any of Audio podcasts (MarketPlace). Audio podcasts stop 3sec before end of audio and it takes 3 click on Play to start again.

Answer (score 0):

I'm just going to answer with an alternative, since I've not used that app enough to know if it can do that.

I use [Downcast](https://itunes.apple.com/app/downcast/id393858566) and I've not had a reason to use anything else. It can definitely do what you want.

For those who are interested, it also has [a Mac app](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/downcast/id668429425?ls=1&mt=12)

The podcasts can be synced via iCloud.

In the iPhone, on the left side of the Play button there is a squiggly icon that is sort of like the infinity symbol with arrows, which will turn on continuous play. It's on when it's red.

The playlist creation is pretty nice too. By default the continuous play loops the current podcast's streamable episodes, but you can for example  make a playlist with all podcasts and listen to all of them continuously.

[image]